# Pentaho CDE Javascript change table background

Tags: javascript, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I have a CDE dashboard and onve of my tables has cells that I want to change background colors based on comparing two cells. The javascript below works well and changes the background as wanted, however it gets rid of the number formatting of %.2f when it loads the table so I end up with many values that have several decimals and no more comas. any advice in formatting this would be great.

```
function f(){    
    this.setAddInOptions("colType","formattedText",function(state){
        if(state.colIdx === 1){
            var rev = state.tableData[state.rowIdx][1];
            var budgetRev = state.tableData[state.rowIdx][2];
            if(rev >= budgetRev){                
                    return {  textFormat: function(v, st) { 
                        
                        return "<div style='background:green;'>"+v+"</div>"; } };
                 }
                 else
                 return {  textFormat: function(v, st) {
                     return "<div style='background:red;'>"+v+"</div>"; } };  
        }        
    });
    
}
```

Comment: You can look Column formats property and set column with format either 'null'  or ‘%.10f’ etc.